# Dois forms enviando dados para uma API em Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Node e Mongoose. Meu problema é o seguinte: No back-end tenho o model de uma entidade chamada Equipment. O  Schema possui diversos parâmetros.

Eu tenho um form para criar um Equipment (esse form funciona normalmente). O form de criação possui diversos inputs que possuem o mesmo nome dos parâmetros do Schema do Mongo.

O problema é que agora estou criando um form para editar o Equipment de acordo com o id. Acontece que eu utilizo um dos inputs para popular outro, consultando outra API. Acredito que esteja acontecendo um conflito por conta do nome dos inputs serem iguais, porém, como vou deixa-los com outro nome para fazer o update?

O primeiro input, após clicado na lupa, envia um get para uma API e popula o segundo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No form de criação isso funciona, já no outro, não é populado.

Modal de criação:

```
<fieldset>
        <!-- Select Basic -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sha1Curve"
            >Curva</label
          >
          <div class="col-md-6 input-container">
            <input
              id="sha1Curve"
              name="sha1Curve"
              type="text"
              placeholder="SHA-1"
              class="form-control input-sm"
            />
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="searchCurve" id="searchCurve"
            ><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg" style="vertical-align: -50%;"></i
          ></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Select Basic -->
        <div
          id="grainDiv"
          name="grainDiv"
          class="form-group"
          style="display: none;"
        >
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grain">Grão</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="grain" name="grain" class="form-control"> </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Modal de edição:

```
<fieldset>
          <!-- Select Basic -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sha1Curve"
              >Curva</label
            >
            <div class="col-md-6 input-container">
              <input
                id="sha1Curve"
                name="sha1Curve"
                type="text"
                placeholder="SHA-1"
                class="form-control input-sm"
              />
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="searchCurve" id="searchCurve"
              ><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg" style="vertical-align: -50%;"></i
            ></a>
          </div>

          <!-- Select Basic -->
          <div
            id="grainDiv"
            name="grainDiv"
            class="form-group"
            style="display: block;"
          >
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grain">Grão</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select id="grain" name="grain" class="form-control"> </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

xml

Maneira que estou realizando o Post:

```
$("#searchCurve").on("click", function() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "URL";

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0) {
    alert(
      "Não foi possível buscar as informações, tente novamente mais tarde."
    );
  }
};

xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  var data = xhr.responseText.split("<nome>");
  var grain;
  // Add equipment
  var grainSelect = document.getElementById("grain");

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    grain = data[i].split(",;");
    console.log(grain[0]);

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = grain[0];

    grainSelect.add(option, null);
    showAddForm();
  }
};

var sha1 = document.getElementById("sha1Curve").value;
console.log(sha1);
var postData = JSON.stringify({ idCurva: sha1.trim() });
console.log(postData);
xhr.send(postData);
```

});

Obrigado

Comment: O name não influência esse conflito, os IDs sim, tem que ser IDs diferentes.

Comment: Entendo! Então se eu alterar os IDS e deixar o mesmo nome do input, o body virá com o nome do atributo 'name'?

Comment: É o mesmo form com 2 inputs enviando pro mesmo lugar na mesma requisição? Porque se for, vai valer o valor do que está em baixo se não me engano, ou vai dar esse "conflito" que você está falando.

Comment: Não, são modais e forms diferentes, porém, chamados na mesma página  HTML